# Как обособить "например" с примером при облепленности другими знаками?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

> (Кстати, до сих пор этот ход существует, и, как и было задумано
>   Вазари, в нём расположена галерея портретов знаменитых флорентийцев.
>   Иногда – следите за сайтом музея Уффици! – **например, в Ночь
>   музеев,** там прогуляться разрешают. Называется это мероприятие
>   *посещение Галереи портретов*.)

Курсив и скобки автора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Иногда – следите за сайтом музея Уффици! – там прогуляться разрешают, **например в Ночь музеев.**

Comment: Это уже корректура за рамками собственно вопроса. И хотелось бы понять, почему вы запятую после "например" сняли. В вашем-то варианте она как раз вполне оправдана.

Comment: 1) Вопрос был о предложении, в котором есть вводное слово "например". Я предложила вариант, в котором не встречаются две обособленные конструкции, поэтому он более удобен для прочтения и оформления. 2) Обособленный оборот  с "например" является уточняющим обстоятельством для наречия "иногда",  при этом по правилу вводное слово входит в обособленный оборот.

Comment: 1) вопрос был о том как поступить в исходной фразе, а не как её изменить. 2) С чего бы это? так было в исходной фразе, но после вашей переделки связь с "иногда" не просматривается. "там разрешают прогуляться, например, в ночь музеев". Про "иногда" тут подумает разве тот, кто видел исходную фразу.

Comment: А такое предложение Вы считает понятным? "Иногда там прогуляться разрешают, например в Ночь музеев". От предложенного мною оно отличается только вставкой.

Comment: Я не хотел бы сейчас обсуждать варианты правки. Их может быть много, но это авторская каденция, да и вопрос не об этом. А непонятным считаю исходное по причине запредельной витиеватости мысли.

Answer (score 2):

Кстати, до сих пор этот ход существует, и, как и было задумано Вазари, в нём расположена галерея портретов знаменитых флорентийцев. Иногда (следите за сайтом музея Уффици!), например в Ночь музеев, там прогуляться разрешают. Называется это мероприятие "посещение Галереи портретов".

Comment: Полностью согласна. Когда идёт попутное замечание в виде целого отрывка речи, ставить скобки нет необходимости, есть же вводное слово. Вот второе замечание  лучше обособить скобками как вставную конструкцию. После например нет запятой, т.к. вводное внутри уточняющего сочетания.

Comment: Ребята, вы не поняли! Открывающая и закрывающая предложение скобки абсолютно необходимы: само повествование о Средневековье!

Comment: Не вижу необходимости во внешних скобках, Людмила права. Но если на иное есть неизбывная воля автора, то придется организовывать вложенную конструкцию. Такой хитромудрый автор, что без скобок его мысль и не передашь нормально.

Answer (score 1):

В исходном варианте запятая после "например" не нужна. Здесь "например в ночь музеев" - обособленная конструкция, в начале которой вводное не обособляется ("не отделяется").

Но если разбираться в авторском стиле, то тут "без стакана" все равно до смысла не докопаешься. Править надо саму фразу, автор самого Тургенева переплюнул по части нагромождения длиннот и вложенности вводных и прочих обособлений. Он сам себя перебивает, как потерявший к концу вечера форму тамада.

Comment: Мимоходов, издайте книгу будущих афоризмов. Начало уже есть (правда, очень понравилось):  "Он сам себя перебивает, как потерявший к концу вечера форму тамада".